# How do old (prior html5) ajax file uploading frameworks work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, http, asyncfileupload

Standard html has [input](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) element with file type.

[Components](http://ajaxuploader.com/) exist which allow asynchronous file upload with progress reporting.

As far as I understand this can be done by splitting file in chunks and sending multiple requests within 'file upload' session. For this to work JavaScript must have access to file's contents, however I do not know how to do it without [FileAPI](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) appeared as part of HTML5.

Comment: are you asking how ajax file upload can be achieved prior without HTML5 or how to create a non-html5 ajax file upload with progress bar?

Comment: I think both variants are really interesting: async (ajax) + progress bar (optional)

Comment: I know about upload events of XHR2 but I'd treat it as part of HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax-ish file upload can be achieved in the following way:

1) embed an iframe on your html page (this will be where the actual upload occurs):

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="about:blank" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

2) set your form target to the iframe:

```
<form target="upload_target" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

3) handle your upload in upload.php

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    // upload files
}
```

4) once upload completes (success or fail) load a view and post a message to the parent window:

```
<script>
    var files = <?php echo json_encode($files); ?>;
    var errors = <?php echo json_encode($errors); ?>;
    var host = 'http://myhost.com';

    for (var key in files) {
        var message = {
            success : files[key].success,
            fileName : files[key].fileName,
            filePath : files[key].filePath
        };

        if (typeof errors[key] != undefined) {
            message.error = errors[key];
        }

        parent.postMessage(
            JSON.stringify(message), // stringify to work around ie8/9
            host
        );

    }       
</script>
```

5) receive the response in your original script:

```
function get_message(cb) {
    cb = cb || function() {};

    handler = handler || function(e) {
        var data = e.data;
        if (typeof data == "string") {
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
            } catch (err) {}
        }

        cb(data, e);
    };


    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child window
    eventer(messageEvent, handler, false);
}

get_message(function() {
    if (data.success == true) {
        // file was successfully uploaded
    } else {
        // file was not successfully uploaded
    }
});
```

[This Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/) has a good example of how to track progress (using modern php). It basically involves a lot of pinging to get the latest progress bar, but I have found you can easily fake progress by slowly incrementing your progress bar from 0 - Random number between 50 and 90 and then once you receive the final "success" message pushing it all the way to 100%